# Proof/Counterexample: If $z$ is a complex number and $z\notin \mathbb Q$, then $\mathbb Q(z)=\mathbb Q(z^3,z^5)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, proof-verification

Proof/Counterexample: If $z$ is a complex number and $z\notin \mathbb Q$, then $\mathbb Q(z)=\mathbb Q(z^3,z^5)$.

First, $\mathbb Q(z)\subseteq \mathbb Q(z^3,z^5)$ would be trivial, right? Then we are left with showing $\mathbb Q(z)\supseteq \mathbb Q(z^3,z^5)$.

If $z\notin \mathbb Q$, then for $z=a+bi$ where $a,b\in \mathbb Q$, $b\ne 0$.

$a+bi=(a+bi)^3$
$a+bi=a^3+3a^2bi-3b^2a-b^3i$
$a+bi=(a^3-3b^2a)+(3a^2b-b^3)i$

Then because $a,b\in \mathbb Q$, $(a^3-3b^2a)+(3a^2b-b^3)i$ is contained in $\mathbb Q(z)$. Thus, $\mathbb Q(z)\supseteq \mathbb Q(z^3,z^5)$?

Does it work like this, or am I way off base with this attempt?

Comment: You are way off base... I don't understand half of your reasoning. Why assume $z \not\in \mathbb{Q}$ when you know it is actually rational by hypothesis? How can you write $a+bi = (a+bi)^3$ without knowing more about $z$?

Comment: I wrote it wrong. $z\notin Q$. Let me fix. Though, that isn't to say it makes the rest of it any better.

Comment: That still doesn't explain why you write $a+bi = (a+bi)^3$. The answer is much simpler than that, by the way.

Comment: Hmm. I was trying to find a way to correlate $z$ and $z^3$/$z^5$.

Comment: **non trivial** part is not $\mathbb Q(z)\supseteq \mathbb Q(z^3,z^5)$ but  $\mathbb{Q}(z)\subset \mathbb{Q}(z^3,z^5)$

Comment: try to see if something simple is true... see if $\mathbb Q(z)=\mathbb Q(z^3,z^5)$ for $z=\sqrt[3]{2}$ and $z=\sqrt[5]{2}$

Comment: To see why you got the "obvious" direction wrong, you might want to recall that $\mathbf{Q}(z)$ is by definition the smallest field which contains both $\mathbf{Q}$ and $z$. Likewise, $\mathbf{Q}(z^3,z^5)$ is the smallest field which contains $\mathbf{Q}$, $z^3$ and $z^5$. Now, what is obvious is that any field which contains $z$ also contains $z^3$ and $z^5$. Hence, $\mathbf{Q}(z)$ contains $\mathbf{Q}$, $z^3$ and $z^5$. Since $\mathbf{Q}(z^3,z^5)$ is the smallest field with that property, $\mathbf{Q}(z)$ contains $\mathbf{Q}(z^3,z^5)$.

Comment: Thank you. That part is making sense now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you are way off base. Your reasoning doesn't make much sense (see my comments above).

In fact you start from the wrong foot. The trivial inclusion is $\mathbb{Q}(z^3,z^5) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}(z)$. Indeed, it's clear that both $z^3$ and $z^5$ can be written as rational fractions of $z$: they're both polynomial in $z$.

To prove the other inclusion $\mathbb{Q}(z) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}(z^3,z^5)$, you need to prove that $z$ can be written in terms of $z^3$ and $z^5$ using only addition, multiplication, division, and multiplication by a rational number. You can do that without using the representation $z=a+bi$, it's purely formal: since $5 \times 2 - 3 \times 3 = 1$, you find that:
$$z = z^1 = z^{5 \times 2 - 3 \times 3} = \frac{(z^5)^2}{(z^3)^3}.$$

Comment: From another example I'm looking at: $\mathbb Q(-3+i\sqrt{2},2-\sqrt{9})=\mathbb Q(i,\sqrt{2})$. I eventually showed: $\sqrt{2}=(2-(2-\sqrt{8}))(2)^{-1}\in \mathbb Q(-3+i\sqrt{2},2-\sqrt{8})$. Is this the procedure to which you're referring?

Comment: No, that's really not the point. What you need to do is write $z = P(z^3,z^5)/Q(z^3,z^5)$ where $P$, $Q$ are polynomials with rational coefficients. If you don't see why that is, you need to reread the definitions of the objects you're studying.

Comment: Not that it matters since it isn't the right procedure but the $\sqrt{9}$ was suppose to be $\sqrt{8}$. I'm definitely missing something fundamental to this material. I can understand writing $z$ in terms of $z^5$ and $z^3$ but I'm not quite understanding the $\mathbb P(z^3,z^5)/\mathbb Q(z^3,z^5)$ part unfortunately. The only nonsense I mustered was $z=\large\frac{z^5}{z^3}\cdot z^{-1}$.

Comment: If $K$ is a field the notazion $K(z)$ means the field of rational functions in $z$ with coefficients in $K$, i.e. the field of all expressions $A(z)/B(z)$ where $A$ and $B$ are polynomials such that $B(z)\neq0$.

Comment: Is there a way to provide an example that isn't a solution or that gives it away?

Comment: @Vincent Have you read my additional hint?

Comment: Yah, that's what gave me the idea that my example had some similarity. I initially thought it as something like: $z^1=z^5\cdot z^2-z^3\cdot z^3$ but $z\ne z^{10}-z^{9}$.

Comment: Well outside of it not making sense for this problem, that doesn't make sense in general as it should be $z^7-z^6$.

Comment: I think I'm going to give it a break for now on this one. When it is eligible for a bounty in a couple days if I haven't got it by then I'll offer a bounty and you can add that part I'm missing in.